# Why SortPartition command does not stop running on the remote cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

In my program, I have a simple sortPartition command as shown in the following snippet. It works fine on a local cluster.

```
SortedData = myData.sortPartition(19, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1);
```

I submitted the program to a remote cluster but, there is a problem and execution does not finish. It seems that the job keeps running and the  command never ends.
My dataset contains only 300k records and 50M bytes. If I reduce the number of records in the dataset to 50k, the program works normally on the remote cluster. Obviously, the memory could not an issue here.
I would like to know, what causes such a problem and any solution to deal with the problem?

Comment: For how long did you wait for the job to finish?
How large is the remote cluster?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's too long. Can you copy&paste the logs of the jobmanager and the task manager running the sort operation on gist.github.com?

Comment: Here is the link, I canceled the task after some minutes in this log, https://gist.github.com/Asppagh/31ee897fee63ef98fdd6

Comment: Sorry for all the requests, can you mabye also share the code of your program? I have the suspicion that the collect() is not working.
Are you collect()'ing more than 10 MB? That's currently the limit I think. Can you try to call collect() on a smaller data set?

Comment: yes, the data size is larger than 10MB. As I mentioned in my question If I reduce the data size it works. 50k record is 8MB but for more than that I just tried 100k records which is almost 16MB, it does not.   But every thing is fine on the local cluster.

Comment: Sorry that I've stopped looking into this. Is it still an issue?